# Max column concept ... sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query -

```
select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, System_Rev
from
(
select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev,
row_number() over(partition by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State order by w1.System_Rev desc) rn
from dbo.DimWorkItem w1  
where w1.System_Id = 1691  
) d
where rn = 1
order by System_Id, TeamProjectSK,System_Rev desc;
```

The output looks like -

```
System_Id    TeamProjectSK  System_State    System_Rev
1691     126              Closed              17
1691     126              Resolved            14
1691     126              Active              13
1691     126              Proposed            2
```

But I want my output to select the row with the highest "System_Rev" value & it should look like -

```
System_Id    TeamProjectSK  System_State    System_Rev
1691         126              Closed              17
```

Now, I tried to re-use the "max" concept using the below query. But it would not work for my help. Please let me know your comments or if there is a better way to get the same result.

```
select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, max(System_Rev)
from
(select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, System_Rev
from
(
    select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev,
        row_number() over(partition by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State order by w1.System_Rev desc) rn
    from dbo.DimWorkItem w1  
    where w1.System_Id = 1691  
) d
where rn = 1
) e
group by System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State
having max(System_Rev)>1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to return the row with the max `System_Rev`, then you need to alter the `row_number()` to partition by the `System_id` and the `TeamProjectSK` only.  Remove the partition by `System_State` as well.

```
select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, System_Rev
from
(
    select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev,
        row_number() over(partition by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK order by w1.System_Rev desc) rn
    from dbo.DimWorkItem w1  
    where w1.System_Id = 1691  
) d
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b671d/1)

Comment: I wanted something different but it helped. It helped me to understand how to use partition better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, System_Rev
from
(
    select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev,
    row_number() over(partition by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State order by w1.System_Rev desc) rn
    from dbo.DimWorkItem w1  
    where w1.System_Id = 1691
) d
where rn = 1
and d.System_Rev = (select max(w2.System_Rev) from dbo.DimWorkItem w2 where w2.System_Id = d.System_Id)
order by System_Id, TeamProjectSK,System_Rev desc;
```